# Oops... {"status":422,"text":"The recipient address is empty"}

Tags: reactjs, forms, email, templates

here is the form component that holds the email and the emailjs function....
I keep getting this error **Oops... {"status":422,"text":"The recipient address is empty"}** in the alert box. **and I don't want to use useRef() that comes from the default emailjs docs... I want to use useState() instead.** The reason is because I want to use the value keyword in the input field and that's why I can't use useRef() but useState()

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

const Email = () => {
  const [name, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setUserMail] = useState("");
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const templateParams = {
      email: email,
      name: name,
      subject: subject,
    };

    emailjs
      .send(
        "service_qr2skm6",
        "template_7w1kzkl",
        templateParams,
        "4s6BipyV-2FaHmzWb"
      )
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("FAILED...", err);
        }
      );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={sendEmail} id="contact-form">
        <label htmlFor="user_name">Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="user_name"
          name="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="user_email">Email:</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="user_email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setUserMail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="subject"
          name="subject"
          value={subject}
          onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Email;
```